# Creating customly selected locations, in Jquery Mobile, with Google Map using existing locations?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

**Disclaimer! I may be making this harder then it is...**

I am attempting to create a Custom Google Maps Webpage for Mobile.  This Google Maps Page would include the current location of the user, and existing restaurants within there location. I know that Google maps already provides this by default.  However I would like to only include my personally picked establishments.

Mission: I am starting a website that will display Dog Friendly Restaurants and Patio Dining. My goal is to provide the user with a list of the closest eater's within there location for the user to bring there dog to.  Ideally I would like to include all the same info a normal restaurant would display on google maps ( phone number, description, ratings, hours.)  except simply displaying a custom icon, and not displaying any none dog friendly restaurants.

Solutions I have tried,

- **Creating a custom map using google maps api.** ( I have the ability to
  create custom markers, titles, and description. However I am unable
  to use existing google maps data. Simply because I don't know how, I haven't found much on using existing data)
- **Creating a shared map** ( I havent dived into this totally, but creating Starred items seems to work, I am just unsure how to present that data on a webpage instead on my own google maps...)
- **Recreating locations from scratch with google maps api** ( Totally a pain to do this, and I would be recreating all of the data I would need.  Essentially using the first solution.)

Has anyone worked on something similar to this?  I am eager to research this further, however I don't want to go down the wrong rabbit hole if there are better solutions.  This is my first experience with custom google maps...

Forgive my noob-like questions as well, I am as junior as they come...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For #2, you can create a custom map with only your "starred" dog-friendly restaurants and use your Map ID to let other people see it. Something like [this map](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=208372276924059963558.000477b2877830f8c5c8c&msa=0&ll=36.035496,120.330505&spn=0.198782,0.363579):

For #1 and #3, you could use the Google Places API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-radar-search

Here is an example using data from Google Places, searching for "dog restaurant".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Search for up to 200 places with Radar Search</title>
    <link href="http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places,visualization&v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
var map;
var infoWindow;
var service;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8668283734, 151.2064891821),
    zoom: 15,
    styles: [
      {
        stylers: [
          { visibility: 'simplified' }
        ]
      },
      {
        elementType: 'labels',
        stylers: [
          { visibility: 'off' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  });

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', performSearch);

  document.forms.kwForm.onsubmit = performSearch;
}

function performSearch() {
  var request = {
    bounds: map.getBounds(),
    keyword: document.forms.kwForm.keywords.value // 'dog restaurant'
  };
  service.radarSearch(request, callback);
  return false;
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    alert(status);
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
    createMarker(result);
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location,
    icon: {
      // Star
      path: 'M 0,-24 6,-7 24,-7 10,4 15,21 0,11 -15,21 -10,4 -24,-7 -6,-7 z',
      fillColor: '#ffff00',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      scale: 1/4,
      strokeColor: '#bd8d2c',
      strokeWeight: 1
    }
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    service.getDetails(place, function(result, status) {
      if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert(status);
        return;
      }
      infoWindow.setContent(result.name);
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width:80%; height:90%; "></div>
    <form id="kwForm">
    <input type=text value="dog restaurant" name="keywords" id="keywords" />
    <input type=submit />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now all you need to do is track your position using Geo-location:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition
```

and add some jQuery Mobile code and you have a working app.

Also possible to use Google [Fusion Tables](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/custom_markers?hl=en) embedded in a Map if you want to import all of the dog-friendly locations into your own database.